# Image not showing in flutter application

Tags: image, flutter, assets

I just load the image from assets folder and image not showing in the application. But when I load the image using network it loads perfectly. 
(I am using linux flat form)
Here is the my code

```
    class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Center(
         child: new Image.asset('assets/images/login_logo.png'),
//Image.network('https://mobile-di.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/flutter-review.jpeg'), //this works
          ),
        );
      }
      }
```

in the pubspec.yaml file

```
assets:
  - assets/images/login_logo.png
```

Comment: Any error in the console output?

Comment: No any errors found

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are adding assets under the `flutter:` in `pubspec.yaml`. Also, check if you are adding spaces before assets. In your example, please check with the path of that asset exist. And make sure that you have assets of that name in your project folder.
 example:

```
flutter:
  assets:
  - lib/img_package/example.png
```